# Access aliases in Gnome "Run Application" dialog

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I'd like to be able to run my aliases from my .bashrc in the "Run Application" dialog that comes up when you hit Alt+F2 in Ubuntu/Gnome.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can't be done. bash aliases work in bash; the alt+F2 window isn't bash. Custom scripts placed in your local PATH, on the other hand, will work just fine.

Comment: ...also, how is this a programming question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications is probably a good place to start. I find these quite hard to follow most of the time, but sometimes you can figure it out. Specifically, the "Desktop Entry Specification".

Also, I don't think you'll be able to use any aliases from `.bashrc`, at least not without writing some kind of wrapper script. I think it needs to be an executable file. Of course, you could just use the good old symlinks- to- same + what's- my- name trick...

(Which, for reference, goes like this:

1. Make a script which uses its own name as a parameter.
2. Make symlinks to said script using the parameter values as the link names.)

---

## Investigating...

Some casual investigation reveals that creating these is fairly simple if you use Nautilus, (at least the version I have):

1. Bring up the context menu for some random file, and use "Open With"->"Open with Other Application".
2. Unfold the "Use a custom command" and type in something like:

   1. `xterm -e 'bash -c "unzip -l %f; sleep 5"'`
3. This results in

   1. the command being run (so don't type `rm -rf`)
   2. a file in `~/.local/share/applications/` called `xterm-usercreated.desktop`

Here at least, I get the follow file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=xterm
MimeType=application/zip;
Exec=xterm -e 'bash -c "unzip -l %f; sleep 5"' %f
Type=Application
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
```

4: Looking at the system xterm .desktop I find this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XTerm
GenericName=
Comment=XTerm: terminal emulator for X
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/xterm-color_32x32.xpm
Exec=xterm
Terminal=false
Categories=X-Debian-Applications-Terminal-Emulators;
```

5: Editing the .usercreated.desktop file to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]                                                                 
Type=Application                                                                
Encoding=UTF-8                                                                  
Name=xtermz                                                                     
Exec=xterm -e 'bash -c "unzip -l %f; sleep 5"' %f                               
Terminal=false                                                                  
Categories=X-Local-WTF
```

6: Run xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate --mode user

7: "xtermz" now shows up in the list... Success!

8: Yuck! This also makes it appear in the main menu, under "Other". Weird!

---

### Some notes:

- In my Debian/testing, `xdg-desktop-menu` and friends (notably `xdg-icon-resource`) live in the `xdg-utils` package.
- You should be able to create a `.desktop` file from scratch.
- You should be able to install the `.desktop` file using `xdg-desktop-menu install` blah blah

Answer (score 4):

There is a very simple solution for Linux Mint and Ubuntu (I did not check it on other distros):

```bash
mkdir ~/bin  #actually, need to run this line just once
cd ~/bin
ln -s /bin/any/your/application.sh YOUR_ALIAS_NAME
```

For example, I like to run `calc` from **Alt+F2** menu, so my script is:

```bash
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/gnome-calculator calc
```

If you want to pass any parameters, you could create a short shell script in `~/bin`:

```bash
#create the file:
echo '#!/bin/sh
firefox --private-window' > ~/bin/pfx
#make my script executable:
chmod 755 ~/bin/pfx
```

---

The solution based on the fact, that there is a file named `.profile` in home dir out of the box. I hope, your already know, what is [`.profile` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer). As part of its job, this file appends `~/bin` to the `$PATH` (if `bin` exists).

I thought, *`bin` in home* is not secure, but this article recommends to follow described way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HomeFolder#Installing_Software_Into_The_Home_Directory

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a symbolic link to /usr/bin: `ln -s <YOUR_ALIAS_PATCH> <ALIAS_NAME>`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the aliases working, so I did this instead:

- Created a shell script to do what I want and put it in my home dir
- Put a link to my shell script in **/usr/bin:**

  - e.g **sudo ln -s ~/bin/MyShellScript.sh /usr/bin/MyShortcutName**

It works!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the aliases working, so I did this instead:

Created a shell script to do what I want and put it in my home dir
Put a link to my shell script in /usr/bin:
e.g `sudo ln -s ~/bin/MyShellScript.sh /usr/bin/MyShortcutName`
It works!

It works because /usr/bin is in your path variable. a better alternative would be to create a hidden directory in your home, like ~/.scripts/

and then add this directory to your path. you can now put all your scripts in that dir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of things.  As Brad Parks + Nostoc says, you could put in your local path a script that executes the program:

```
$ cat my/local/path/terminal
#! /bin/bash
gnome-terminal
```

If you don't want to do this for your many aliases, then add a single "alias executor" to your local path:

```
$ cat my/local/path/myAlias
#! /bin/bash
CMD="$*"
eval "$CMD"
```

Then, in the dialog, you would type "myAlias aliasedProgram arg1 arg2 etc".

Answer (score 1):

I created this script under the name /usr/bin/b, and gave it global read/execute permission:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
eval "$@"
```

Now I can use the command

```
b foo arg1 arg2
```

which basically runs

```
foo arg1 arg2
```

as if it had been typed in an interactive shell.  It's fine to use aliases, compound commands, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Came upon this post years later hoping for an answer that doesn't involve creating symlinks.

IMO, you're going the wrong way by trying to use the run dialog.
You should be using a "drop down terminal" such as [guake](http://guake-project.org) instead if you'd like access to your .bashrc.

Both a drop down terminal and the gnome run dialog can be used in a pinch to summon a program and then be hidden away again. But, the run dialog does not have access to your bash environment. It can only access programs in /bin(s).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alt-f2 to run commands outside the terminal, I use gnome-do instead; it is much more convenient & flexible (once it's set up). You're still not going to be able to run shell "aliases", but you can configure gnome-do to use the "files and folders" plugin, and then any "*.desktop" applications you like to execute will be available for running, opening, etc. You can also have shell scripts executed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to @YAG.

i created a bash script in /usr/local/bin called 'my':

```
echo -e '#!/usr/bin/bash\n~/bin/$@' > ~/temp
sudo cp ~/temp /usr/local/bin/my
rm ~/temp
```

Now if i want to call a script inside ~/bin from Alt+F2 i just type:

```
my script.sh
```

The advantages are that all users will access their own ~/bin directory, and you don't have to make a new symlink for each ~/bin/* file.

The disadvantage is that you need to type 'my' everytime, and can't count on the auto-complete feature of alt+f2 to complete 'script.sh'

Answer (score 0):

Simply type: bash -ic 'MY_ALIAS'